# Issues installing onnxruntime on rasberry pi OS

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi-os, image, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, packages

I was following a tutorial for [removing backgrounds in images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715507/how-to-load-or-infer-onnx-models-in-edge-devices-like-raspberry-pi) with python
and came across an issue when running `pip install rembg` on a Raspberry Pi.

The issue appears to be wit a requirement to install [onnxruntime](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/get-started/with-python.html).

The Error I am getting is the following:

```
    Code: Select all
    
    ERROR: Cannot install rembg==2.0.28, rembg==2.0.29, rembg==2.0.30, rembg==2.0.31, rembg==2.0.32, rembg==2.0.33, rembg==2.0.34, rembg==2.0.35, rembg==2.0.36, rembg==2.0.37, rembg==2.0.38, rembg==2.0.39, rembg==2.0.40, rembg==2.0.41 and rembg==2.0.43 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
    
    The conflict is caused by:
        rembg 2.0.43 depends on onnxruntime
        rembg 2.0.41 depends on onnxruntime
        rembg 2.0.40 depends on onnxruntime
        rembg 2.0.39 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
        rembg 2.0.38 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
        rembg 2.0.37 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
        rembg 2.0.36 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
        rembg 2.0.35 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
        rembg 2.0.34 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
        rembg 2.0.33 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
        rembg 2.0.32 depends on onnxruntime>=1.13.1
        rembg 2.0.31 depends on onnxruntime>=1.13.1
        rembg 2.0.30 depends on onnxruntime~=1.13.1
        rembg 2.0.29 depends on onnxruntime==1.13.1
        rembg 2.0.28 depends on onnxruntime==1.13.1

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

**Here is what I am using:**
Raspberry Pi 4 B with Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit)

**Here is what I have tried to do to fix the issue:**

When attempting to

1. running `pip install onnxruntime`
2. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
3. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
4. Followed these instructions to [build and run as an IoT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715507/how-to-load-or-infer-onnx-models-in-edge-devices-like-raspberry-pi)

I get the same error.

However, if I change the Micro SD card with another OS such as Ubuntu Desktop 23.04 (64-bit)  or Ubuntu MATE `pip install rembg` works. No errors with onnxruntime. I also tested this with a couple virtual machines and I get the same results leading me to believe it has something to do with the RaspberryPi OS. But I am not sure what it is.

**My questions to the community:**

1. What could be causing the issue of installing onnxruntime on the
   Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) OS and not with Ubuntu if it still the same
   board?
2. What could be a fix or best way to start looking into the
   root cause?

I also posted this on https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2111963#p2111963

Answer (score 0):

I was using a 32Bit system instead of 64Bit. Imaged the MicroSD to a 64BIT and it worked. Desktop vm was also 32.
I see in the [documentation that 32BIT is possible](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/build/inferencing.html)e if built manually.